# A leveling on a non-empty set $A$ is a function $d$ from $A \times A$ into $A$....

Tags: functions

I need help figuring out these definitions and the questions below. I am having a hard time following the definitions and need guidance on how to read them better.

> 1. A leveling on a non-empty set $A$ is a function $d$ from $A \times A$ into $A$.
> 2. Let $d$ denote a leveling on a on $A$. Then an invariance element of $A$
>      under $d$ is any element $a$ in $A$ such that for all of $x$ in $S$
>      $d(a,x)=d(x,a)=x$.
> 3. Let $d$ denote a leveling on $A$ and let $a$ be an element of $D$. Then an
>      opposite of a value $d$ is any element of $z$ of $A$ that for some
>      invariance element $a$ of S under $d$, $d(a,z)=d(z,a)=x$.
>
> Question 1: Give a leveling $b$ on $\{d,e,f\}$ such that $e$ is an invariance element of
>   $\{d,e,f\}$ under $d$. Question 2: Give a leveling $b$ on $\{d,e,f\}$ such that an opposite of
>   $d$ is $f$.

Can you please help me figure this out and explain to me exactly what these definitions are saying?

Comment: Are you sure about 3)? It sounds more natural that $z$ is an oppositive value of $a$ if $d(a,z)=d(z,a)=x$ where $x$ is an invariance element. Btw, on base of 2) it can be shown that there is not more than $1$ invariance element.

Comment: Too many typos ... please, check. :)

Answer (score 1):

For 1 :

> A leveling on a non-empty set $A$ is a function $d$ from $A \times A$ into $A$

where, in general, $A \times B$ is the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the sets $A,B$, i.e. the set $\{ (x,y) | x \in A, y \in B \}$, where $(x,y)$ is called : *ordered couple* of $x$ and $y$.

Thus a function $d : A \times A \to A$ is a funtion that "assign" to an orderd couple of elements of $A$ a "value" in $A$, i.e. an element of $A$.

In *number theory*, an example of such a function is the "sum" :

> $+ : \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$

simply because $n+m=k$ can be written as $+(n,m)=k$.

---

For 2 : with the above example in *number theory*, an *invariance* for the sum is :

> any element $a \in A$ such that, for all of $x \in S, d(a,x)=d(x,a)=x$:

if we set $A=S= \mathbb Z$, the invariance for the sum is a number $a$ such that $a+n=n+a=n$, for all $n$: it is clearly $0$.

---

For 3 : we have that the *opposite* of a value $x$ is any element $z$ of $A$ such that for some invariance element $a$ of $S$ under $d, d(x,z)=d(z,x)=a$.

Again with the above example, for any $n \in \mathbb Z$, its *opposite* with respect to the invariance element $0$ for the sum is $-n$, because :

> $n+(-n)=(-n)+n=0$.

---

---

*Added*

Assuming that :

> **Question 1**: Give a *leveling* $b$ on $\{ d,e,f \}$ such that $e$ is an *invariance element* of $\{ d,e,f \}$ under $b$ (and **not** $g$)

we have $A=S= \{ d,e,f \}$ and we have to define :

> $b : A \times A \to A$

such that :

> $b(x,e)=b(e,x)=x$, for all of $x \in A$.

$A$ has three elements; thus $A \times A$ has nine elements :

> $(d,d), (d,e), (d,f), (e,d), (e,e), (e,f), (f,d), (f,e), (f,f)$;

we have to define the value of the function $b$ for each of them, ensuring the above condition for the *invariance element* $e$.

This drives our choice, becuase we must have :

> $b(d,e)=b(e,d)=d$,
>
> $b(e,e)=e$,
>
> $b(f,e)=b(e,f)=f$.

We are left with the definition of $b(d,d), b(d,f), b(f,d), b(f,f)$.

If we set :

> $b(d,f)=b(f,d)=e$,

we finally answer also to :

> **Question 2**: Give a *leveling* $b$ on $\{ d,e,f \}$ such that an opposite of $d$ is $f$.

Comment: How should I be approaching Question 1: Give a leveling b on {d,e,f} such that e is an invariance element of {d,e,f} under g. and Question 2: Give a leveling b on {d,e,f} such that an opposite of d is f then? I am most confused with what definitions I should choose to solve these problems? Should I be looking at all three definitions?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo. Yes, it should be under d.

Comment: This is hard. So how could I even develop a function b where for b(x,e)=b(e,x)=x. Does the function b have all of the same elements? Could you give me an example?

Comment: So for example 2, because we must have b(d,e) = b(e,d) = f and b(f,f) = f, so we can conclude that the answer for Question 2 is b(d,e), b(e,e)?

Comment: So for Question 2 b(d,e), b(e,e) is incorrect? How so? Can you show me this?